# How to change the memory management of Browser for increasing the memory of Session storage and local storage using java script

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to store the more than 10 MB data in session storage of HTML5.. but its  not allowing me to do.. can we programmetically using java script increase the the memory using system memory..

Comment: Highly unlikely any browser would let you do this. Look into other storage API's with larger limits.

Comment: @TedNoelker Cookies have smaller limits, thank goodness. Could you imagine sending 10MB+ per-request?

Comment: BRO i am getting 25MB data i am trying tohandle it in session to increase the execution...and efficiency..otherwise i have to put everything in JAVA hash map..last option..

Answer (score 0):

No.  There is currently no Javascript programmatic control over the amount of data you can put in Local Storage.  These limits are provided to keep any single page from using an unreasonable amount of system resources and are thus not controllable from Javascript.

Browser plugins have access to potentially more space and can request storage.

There's a new quota management API that has been proposed here for extended offline storage here: https://www.w3.org/TR/quota-api/, but I'm not aware of existing implementations.

There are other types of storage with their own limits as described here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/storage/

Answer (score 0):

The amount of storage available in HTML5, assuming you are referring to [Local Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp), is browser dependent. [The spec suggests that browsers allow at least 5MB per origin](https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-webstorage-20091222/#disk-space). However, that is a recommendation, not a rule. Some browsers allow the user to increase/decrease the available storage on a per-origin basis and/or globally.

It would be a big security issue if you could change this with JavaScript. Imagine, I could crash your system by filling it with garbage.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the answer will be **No.** you can't storage that much data in browser. Only 5MB allowed for local storage. However some browsers are storing 10MB data in browser [Please visit here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/quota-research/) for more info. Here they have mentioned it 10MB but not tested.